# Java VS RAM: How much data Java can handle without 'OutOfMemory'?

Tags: java, servlets, memory, memory-management, out-of-memory

We all have beaten with the error of `OutOfMemory`. It occurs if we store more characters than the `String` limit, if we exceed the `StringBuffer` limit, if we exceed the `ArrayList` limit and so on. There is a large list. But it is worth noting that world's biggest Big Data projects are built with Java, including Amazon. So I have a question. Can Java store a 70 MB file in memory? This file contains text, and each single line of this file will be saved as an element in a `LinkedList`. So, if the file got 200,000 lines, the the `LinkedList` will have 200,000 elements. Imagine I have a RAM of 4-5 GB.

Can Java handle something like this, without throwing `OutOfMemory`? I do not want to manually adjust the heap size anyway.

What is your advice?

**Update**

Don't target to 70MB. Imagine in future, this fill be 300GB. I have a RAM of 500 GB (Yes, I am in a big data project, RAM is bigger than this anyway). Now what?

Comment: You can map the file into memory and store pointers to different lines. It is even easier if lines have the same length, of course. And file mappings don't "pollute" the heap. See `FileChannel.map()`.

Comment: This is more a JVM setting than language limitation.'

Comment: @fge: Please have a look at the update.

Comment: @thatidiotguy: Please have a look at the update.

Comment: Why do you not want to "manually adjust the heap size"? What's wrong with setting a reasonable heap size for your application?

Comment: @meriton: Because it is a Patch. 70MB file is my test File. Original file is 4 TeraBytes.

Comment: @fge: Pointers in Java????

Comment: I meant offsets, really (into the file). Instead of storing full lines, you only store offsets, and when you want to read the file, you  read from the mapping instead (edit: but since your file is 4 TB, you'd need multiple mappings per file).

Comment: Can someone explain why my answer was immediately downvoted? Did I completely miss the point of the question or something?

Comment: Ah, I see now. The asker of the question specifically said "I do not want to manually change the heap size." **Good luck changing the heap size without changing the heap size.**

Comment: @fge:Can you please give me the link for this "Mapping" ?

Answer (score 2):

You can change how much memory the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) has when running your program by adding the following parameters to the program start.

- `-Xms<initialSize>`
- `-Xmx<maxSize>`

Replace `initialSize` and `maxSize` with whatever fits your requirements (and limitations).

**Example**

The following will run HelloWorld.class with an initial heap size of 64 MB and a maximum heap size of 256 MB.

> java -Xms64m -Xmx256m HelloWorld

Answer (score 1):

The answer?  "It depends", because of the generational memory model.

`OutOfMemoryError` usually happens when you exhaust perm gen, not overall memory.

Your operating system has an effect, too.  A 32-bit JVM will now allow you a heap larger than 1.2-1.5GB, because the operating system and JVM take their share.

A 64-bit operating system and JVM will let you have much more RAM for the heap.

The only limits on StringBuffer and List are ints for indexes and sizes (Integer.MAX).

Comment: Please have a look at the update I made.

Comment: Adds nothing.  You'll have to change JVM configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Java can easily store a 70MB file in memory

Comment: Please have a look at the update I made.

Comment: I thought Java cannot.

Answer (score 0):

Buffering is always a reasonable answer when processing large amounts of data from files: you almost never need to load up a full 1-10-100 GB file in memory, but only small chunks. If you do, you should probably rethink your design.

Moreover, scaling out a 'big data' system becomes cost effective only if you can use convenience hardware (cheap low end servers) where the available resources, memory among others, are limited (think under 16 GB per machine or even less, some early tests used machines with only 2 GB RAM), as described in Google's MapReduce original paper.

Following the ideas above, most Java based (and not) big data technologies most likely never need to load huge amounts of data in memory. For example Hadoop processes individual rows of data, dumping the result back on disk as soon as it's done.

So unless you have files where each row is 4 GB in size, this is a non issue. And if you do, you should probably rethink your design, data gathering strategy, infrastructure or kick out the evil mind who decided it was a good idea to have your data organized that way.

Finally, to address your question specifically, if you have a server with 500 GB RAM available to you, why don't you run some tests? Try different file sizes, different file types (JSON, XML, plain, CSV) and different ways to load up (scanners, buffered readers, etc.) and keep the data in memory (maps, lists of strings, DOM-like objects, etc.). Then please share your findings with us because this sounds like fun!

Comment: Thanks for the relpy. One line will not take 4TB. Lets say the entire text file will be 200GB.

Comment: Again, try it yourself. And again, are you sure you need to load the whole thing in memory?

Comment: That is what I am asked to do.